# replace characters starting from the nth occurence of another character in a string via regex

Tags: regex

How do I replace the whitespace beginning from the last comma in the following string:

```
foo, bar, 2 3 4 5
```

should yield:

```
foo ,bar ,2345
```

The whitespace up to the second comma should remain intact.

Comment: What other technology do you have? This would be overly complex with regex alone.

Comment: Shouldn't it yield `foo, bar,2345`?  Or is it also supposed to move spaces from right side of comma to left?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary good point! Regex alone will only find, not replace. Are we talking perl, js, what?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: Overly complex? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for

```
\s+(?=[^,]*$)
```

and replace with nothing. This matches whitespace characters only if there are no commas further ahead in the string.

If you want to implement the rule "all whitespace after the second comma in the string, regardless of whether there are more commas after that", then you need a regex engine that can handle indefinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions; currently only .NET and JGSoft engines do this. If you're using one of those, fine:

```
(?<=(?:,[^,]*){2})\s+
```

matches whitespace if it's preceded by at least two commas.

Comment: +1, very elegant. I underestimated positive look aheads. I worried not all engines support them. Way to show me up :)